# Method type returning an object using this.type as a type parameter

Tags: scala, types

I have the following records and DAOs:

```
abstract class SuperRecord
class Record1 extends SuperRecord
class Record2 extends SuperRecord
abstract class SubRecord extends SuperRecord
class SubRecord1 extends SubRecord

abstract class DAO[T <: SuperRecord] extends scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Table[T]
object DAO1 extends DAO[Record1]
object DAO2 extends DAO[Record2]
abstract class SubDAO extends DAO[T <: SubRecord]
object SubDAO1 extends SubDAO[SubRecord1]
```

Then SuperRecord and Record have the following methods

```
abstract class SuperRecord {
  def table: DAO[T] forSome {type T <: SuperRecord}
}

class Record1 extends SuperRecord {
  def table = DAO1
}
```

All of this satisfies the type-checker.  However, I'd like to change the signature of "def table" in SuperRecord to indicate that T *IS* the record type, i.e. in Record1 the type of table is DAO[Record1] instead of DAO[T :< SuperRecord], something like

```
def table: DAO[this.type]
```

or

```
def table: T forSome {type T <: DAO[U forSome {type U <: this.type }]}
```

neither of which satisfies the type system.  Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible in Scala, and if so what signature for "table" should I use?

Comment: What is the problem with the first alternative `def table: DAO[this.type]`?

Comment: @david: the error I get when setting `def table = DAO1` in `Record1` is, found: DAO1.type; required: DAO[Record1.this.type]; Note: Record1 >: Record1.this.type (and DAO1.type <: DAO[Record1]), but class DAO is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)

Comment: Instead of setting it to `DAO1`, what if you set it to `def table = new DAO[this.type](""){
      def * : ColumnBase[self.type] = ???
    }`? Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the level of type specificity you want with the following:

```
abstract class SuperRecord[T <: SuperRecord[T]] {
  def table: DAO[T]
}
abstract class DAO[T <: SuperRecord[T]] extends Table[T]
```

which allows you to define:

```
class Record1 extends SuperRecord[Record1] {
  def table = DAO1
}
object DAO1 extends DAO[Record1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to keep the question open for a few days to see if anybody has an answer that keeps all of the typing tomfoolery contained to "def table" (rather than requiring that I re-type all of my classes), and barring that I'll accept this as the solution and set about refactoring

Comment: Absolutely - we'd all like to see if this can be done better!